# How to open Desktop website in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I tried [Advanced Web view](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) for displaying desktop site into mobile but problem is like that when i open application first time that time it's working perfect and displaying desktop site but when open next time it's displaying mobile website in webview.

Is there is any reason or may be cache of browser it storing every time.

I also tried to clear cache when page finished in webview but it's not working.

Comment: for that u need to set **setUserAgent**

Comment: did u try to find on google?

Comment: After reading AdvancedWebView.java I found **setDesktopMode** use it and check it's working or not.

Comment: i used it but problem is it is not working when i open application next time @bdevloper

Comment: in setUseAgent what can it set @bdevloper

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0

Comment: do modify the AdvancedWebView and set `newUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0` and then `webSettings.setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);`

Comment: it is not working

Comment: try this webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20 Safari/537.31");